# n^n is Ω (n!), is the statement true or false?

Tags: algorithms

n^n is Ω (n!), is the statement true or false?
n^n has a steeper curve thus this is false?
I am not sure at all

Comment: $n!$ is approximately $\sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$ from Stirling formula

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{n^n}{n!}&=\frac{\overbrace{n\cdot n\cdots n}^{n\text{ times}}}{1\cdot2\cdots(n-1)\cdot n}\\&=\frac n1\cdot\frac n2\cdots\frac n{n-1}\frac nn\\
&>n\cdot1\cdots1 
\end{align}$$
so that $$n^n>n\cdot n!$$ and $$n^n\in\Omega(n!)$$